# Unable to identify the element even using full xpath

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I'm unable to identify the element in all the below cases. Please help me to identify the problem in my code.

HTML code :

```
<div id="DetailedNavigationTree" class="SItree">
    <div style="margin-left: 0px; margin-right: 10px; white-space: nowrap;">
       <img src="/irj/portalapps/com.sap.portal.design.portaldesigndatathemes        /portal/Test_theme/nav/treeview/ico12_treeleaf.gif?7.0.24.1.6"/>
       <img id="DetailedNavigationTree/navurl://cd82866421cb92cf96c103eb19061574" src="/irj/portalapps/com.sap.portal.design.portaldesigndata/themes/portal/ford_theme/common/1x1.gif?7.0.24.1.6"/>
       <a class="SItreeText" href="#" style="word-wrap: normal; white-space: nowrap;">Test CRM Centre</a>
</div>
```

I want to click the element in tag <`a - Test CRM Centre`

Code I tried :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".SItreeText")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Test CRM Centre")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/table/tbody[2]/tr[2]/td[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/a")).click();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#DetailedNavigationTree")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '#')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id = 'navNodeAnchor_2_0']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '#')]")).click();
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//html/body/table/tbody/tr[1]/td/div[1]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td/span/table/tbody[2]/tr[2]/td[3]/div/div/div[2]/div/a")));
```

Comment: You will need to post a more "Simplistic HTML" structure ... but all the levels. 
In this case you are looking for `body->table->table row 1->table date-> div 1` and so on are you use there is a table in a table data in table row 1 with a table in a table data and an A in position of of a TR in the third in nested divs?

Comment: Hi Kenneth Clark, Please let me know how to post correct HTML Structure. Sorry i'm posting question first time.

Comment: Hi, I have given the proper Structure HTML. Please help me to resove this issue

Comment: You will need to post .. just the HTML Structure of the page and the div so keep it minimal content `<HTML><BODY><TABLE><TR><TD><TABLE...></TD></TR></TABLE></BODY>` that will help a bunch

Comment: is `DetailedNavigationTree` unique in your page?

Comment: Hi Toyo, Yes. That is unique

Comment: Why `driver.switchTo().frame`? Is there any iframe?

Comment: Do you have an `xmlns` (namespace declaration) in your "HTML"?

Answer (score 2):

There could be several reasons why you are not able to identify an element. Some of your selectors in general look correct to me. Perhaps answering following questions may help,

Do you have more than one link available on the page? If so, you may need to filter the element you want to click even further and avoid using a generic selector

```
 List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Test CRM Centre"));
 System.out.println(links.size());
```

Do you have any synchronization issues? Like are you trying to click on the linkText before even its rendered? In that case you could use explicit wait

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
 WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.linkText("Test CRM Centre")));
 link.click();
```

Is your element inside any frame? If so you would need to switch to the frame before you could find the element

```
 WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.id("myframeid"));
 driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
```

Edit#1
May be you should try clicking on the image,

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#DetailedNavigationTree>div>img[id^='DetailedNavigationTree']"));
element.click();
```

Comment: Hi,when i use the aboue code i'm getting 0 printed  List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.linkText("Test CRM Centre"));
 System.out.println(links.size());

Comment: I see..do you have answers to the other two questions I asked.

Comment: Do you have any synchronization issues? - No Is your element inside any frame? - How to check Frame info. Pls help

Comment: open dev tool bar in chrome or use firebug. Inspect the element and check if the element is within an `iframe` tag

Comment: There is no iframe tag in HTML

Comment: Try clicking the `img` above the link. I added the code in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `//a[@class="SItreeText"]`.

Comment: Hi olyv, Thanks for your reply. But Still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

try `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#DetailedNavigationTree .SItreeText")).click();`

Comment: Same issue Tolo. Thanks for the reply

Comment: I copied your fragment of html in a file changing `href='http://www.google.com'` and did `driver.get("file:///C:/Users/myName/Dev/src/test.html");
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".SItreeText")).click();`. The browser navigated to Google

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
By.xpath("//div[@id='DetailedNavigationTree']//a[contains(text(),'Test CRM Centre')]")
```

or

```
By.cssSelector("#DetailedNavigationTree a.SItreeText")
```

Comment: Same issue Santoshsarma

Comment: Have you verified locator in firebug? Is there more than one element with same locator? Is it in iframe ? Can you provide full html?